# Visual Studio Code shortcut to display autocomplete list before typing

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am trying to display all possible words after putting the cursor in certain place in the code.

The autocomplete (suggestions) list appears when I start writing/typing:

[image]

However, I would like to see all suggested words even before typing.

I tried <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, however it was a system shortcut for Search in macOS:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's *Ctrl* + space: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf (Also described on the [keybindings page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_rich-languages-editing))

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56143239/how-to-trigger-vscode-intellisense-using-keyboard-on-osx/59774240#59774240

Comment: It's called `trigger suggest`, default to `ctrl + space`, could change in `File -> Preference -> Keyboard shortcuts`

Comment: docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_intellisense-features

Answer (score 340, accepted):

In case you are a [CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters) user using Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will not work, since it is used to switch [IME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method)s.

There is another keyboard shortcut for triggering suggestions:

- <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (Mac)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (Windows)

Also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59774240/6064933).

---

VS code version: 1.41.1

Comment: Confirmed ! Awesome. I upgraded VS Code to 1.141.1, and `Option + esc` works like a charm.

Comment: Do I have to press control + space every time? In my previous system it used to show without pressing. Any idea why it's not working anymore?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is CJK and IMEs ?

Comment: @andrew [CJK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_characters) means China, Japan and Korea, which have similar character systems. [IME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) stands for input method which is necessary to input CJK characters, contrary to the English language.

Comment: Thank you, I have no words. Upvoted you, of course.
It works on Mac Studio, Ventura, M1 Max

Comment: Oops! This did not work for me because `Option-Esc` is tied to "Read selected text out loud" on my macOS. `Fn-Control-Space` and `Command-I` worked.

Comment: Not sure why you single out CJK languages. This is true for ANY multi-language setup. For example, I am using SWE keyboard and I have to use ALT+ESC.

Comment: @DanieleTesta Thanks for pointing out, I am a CJK user, so I can only test for CJK

Answer (score 131):

I solved this problem using <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: The question is about MacOS, also , fn does not exist with touchbar (Macbook 2018)

Comment: Thank you Sir!
That is a correct answer for OSX users!

Comment: It works on Macbook pro 2019 on BigSur. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Worked for Macbook pro 2019 on Monterey too. Thanks!

Comment: Works for MBP (M2 Pro) 2023

Comment: Works for everyone using Mac

Comment: Thank you, it works on Mac Studio, Ventura, M1 Max

Answer (score 78):

"change input source" keyboard shortcut should be disabled

To disable it->

- Go to system preferences -> keyboard -> input sources
- add a new input source (choose ABC)
- Go to shortcuts tab (inside of keyboard settings)
- Click on input sources on the left
- disable the "select previous input source" shortcut

restart your vs code and now ctrl+space will show quick suggestions.

Comment: wow. thank you so much!!

Comment: Worked for a German QWERTZ keyboard layout! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Worked great, I struggled a lot finding this keyboard shortcut, thank you very much! ❤️

Comment: One super import thing: Change that in your macOS System settings!!

Answer (score 70):

You can use the following *alternative* keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> (mentioned in the official VS Code [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf) for "Trigger suggestion")
- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

Comment: Best answer: `⌘` +`I`

Comment: I like `⌘` + `I`

Comment: Unluckily, it is for copilot `inlineChat.start`

Comment: `cmd`+`i` conflicts with Copilot chat

Answer (score 25):

The shortcut for the "Trigger Suggest" command is `⌃Space` (ctrl+space) — as [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341555/visualcode-shortcut-to-display-autocomplete-list-before-typing-in-macos/51342532#comment89656585_51341555).

Most default shortcuts can be [found in the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings), which will automatically show the correct keybindings for the system you're on. In other words, if you visit the page on a Mac, you'll see Mac keybindings.

Additionally, you can:

- go to **Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts** (on a Mac) and search for keybindings based on the command you want to execute
- open up "show all commands" (`⇧⌘P` on a Mac) and search for the command there, allowing you to either view the keybinding for that command, or simply navigate to it directly from the search

Of course you'd have to have some idea of what the command's name might be. And in this case, a search for "suggest" would suffice.

Comment: To add to this response, if the hotkey is set, even if disabled, it will not work. To fix it you have to enable it, remap and disable it back again.

Answer (score 17):

If you use too many keyboard layouts, maybe the MacOS shortcut might be active. You can disabled ^(Ctrl)+Space shortcuts for MacOS.

- **System Preferences>Keyboard>Shorcuts>Input Sources> Disable Select the previous input source.**

You can use next shortcut for change input sources.**Ctrl+Alt+Space**

Comment: Great! I was getting language change on CTRL + Space in VS Code, but after disabling the change language shortcut from System Preferences AND restarting the VS Code it started to work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

when I was set up 2 keyboards with different layouts, and it turn out it overrides the `^+Space` behavior, so this is how fix it:

- Go to system preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard shortcuts
  [image]
- Click on input sources
- and disable the "select previous input source" shortcut
  [image]