# How to trigger VS Code IntelliSense using keyboard on OS X?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

All the docs [keep referring](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging) to `⌃Space` to launch IntelliSense so as to get *suggestions* for config files, launch configs etc. As I understand from [this chart](https://superuser.com/questions/46452/weird-symbols-for-key-combinations-on-a-mac) that translates to the key combination <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd>.

However on Mac OS X 10.11 `⌃Space` only opens [Spotlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_(Apple)). How do I trigger VS Code InteliSense from the keyboard on a Mac?

Comment: vscode v1.50 is adding `Cmd+I` (that's a capital "eye") to also trigger intellisense on the mac, and `Ctrl+I` on Windows and Linux - see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_50.md#trigger-intellisense

Comment: FTR in later macOS revisions `^Space` is _"Select the previous input source"_, and my preferred best quickfix/compromise for this is a single untick of that particular shortcut (in _System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Input Sources_). You retain the ability to cycle input source by the default `^⌥Space`.

Comment: @Mark You should write that as an answer, it is super useful IMO

Comment: @Sagivb.g Thanks, I just added it as an answer since it wasn't mentioned in the others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`^Space` means `Ctrl + Space`, not `Cmd + Space` (which definitely triggers Spotlight).

You can customize keyboard shortcuts [according to the doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_key-bindings).

Comment: Thanks for the details - I restored my osx keyboard shotcuts (I guess at some stage some of them got changed) and now Spotlight does not open on ctl-space. I had to restart vscode and now ctl-space works as expected.

Answer (score 70):

I am using vs code on Mac and I am a CJK user. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is a shortcut for switching IMEs on my Mac.

If you open the keyboard shortcut pane (just press `Command + K`, then followed by `Command+S`), then search for `trigger suggest`, you will find that there are actually two shortcuts for this function:

[image]

So in case `Ctrl + Space` is taken by other programs. You can use `Option + Esc` to trigger suggestions. If you are using a Windows keyboard, `Option` key is `Alt`. You can also change the keybindings for this command as suggested by @Atilla Baspinar.

Comment: And the command is called that because _IntelliSense_ is to "Suggest", what _Xerox_ is to "Copy". ™️-protected 

Comment: If you are using Mac OS and have multiple languages for your keyboard input macos might be highjacking `Ctrl+Space`. Check **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts** for any active keyboard shortcuts with `Ctrl+Space`

Answer (score 21):

vscode v1.50 added <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (that's a capital "eye") to also trigger intellisense on the mac, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Windows and Linux - see [v1.50 Release Notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_50#_trigger-intellisense):

> ##### Trigger IntelliSense
>
> For years, `Ctrl+Space` has been the predominant keybinding to trigger
> IntelliSense. However, on macOS and Windows, the same keybinding is
> used to toggle between keyboard layouts. To minimize confusion, we
> added another keybinding to trigger IntelliSense: on Windows and Linux
> it's `Ctrl+I`, and on macOS it's `Cmd+I`.

Debug

Comment: Great! Cmd + I is much better for me. ^space is not very convenient

Comment: Cmd + I is now copilot..

Comment: @AlanDaniel The keybinding `ctrl/Cmd + I` is still there - the commands have difference context clauses.

Answer (score 11):

From the top menu in VSCode (on MacOS) select

> Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

A list of shortcuts is displayed on code area.

Search for "**Trigger Suggest**". The default value is `⌃Space`.

Double click and change according to your like.

I made it `Ctrl+.`